# Attaching a Workflow to an approved Document puts it into Draft

Tags: workflow, approval, draft

I have an issue where a Worklof (Basically just a request/confirmation Workflow to read the approved document) puts the document into draft status.

I was tasked to fix this behaviour, the file should still be Approved without a new Version.

The Workflow has a Status field on the Document which gets updated as soon as the Workflow is attached to the Document, which changes its approval status.

How can I fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The workflow was set to update its status.

Removing that checkmark in SP Designer causes an Element to not change at all so it won't get put into draft mode.